# Best practice: Conditional statements in javascript with array data type

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, conditional-statements

I encountered a piece of code where instead of checking each and every possible error condition directly accessing an array element looks to have good time complexity(Assuming, please correct me if I am wrong), is this a good practice?

with proper conditional verification:

```
if (!(results && results.length > 0 && results[0] != undefined)){
  return reject(new Error('results not found.'));
}
```

accessing array element and verifying on a single go:

```
if (!(results && results[0])){ 
  return reject(new Error('results not found.'));
}
```

If it is, is it worth compromising readability to the complexity?

Comment: The first version is better. Second one will throw an uncaught error if `results` is `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Those two example snippets do different things. It depends on the context which one is better suited for the job. Performance in this case seems rather irrelevant.

Comment: @str I was assuming to check the length of the array, we need to loop through each and every elements which will make a little difference, what do you think?

Comment: I think it is more important that the code actually works than that it might be small neglibile fraction of a millisecond faster.

Comment: @blex I updated, for this question I am considering only the length part.

Comment: With your update, that is just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

From your two examples, it seems your requirements are to ensure that:

1. results is defined and is an array
2. results has atleast 1 element

Considering these two requirements, I would go for more expressive and readable approach rather than caring for negligible performance benefit. Array element access is still O(1). Anyway, what would be more expressive and readable instead?

```
if(Array.isArray(results) && results.length > 0) {
   // do something
}
```

If you still insist on choosing b/w your two versions, I would like to clarify that is better to use `typeof` when checking for the existence of array element rather than the value of that element.

With that said, I would go for version 1 (preferably, without `results[0] != undefined` part) since it's more explicit.

**Why not `results[0] != undefined`?**

It might seem good to explicitly check for the element *to be defined*. However, shouldn't this check be whilst creating the array? Your array should not have `undefined` elements to begin with. You should ensure the element that you are about to `push()` isn't `undefined`.